# HTML Video url using Iframe not working on Android Version 4.4.2

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-studio, android-webview

> Using an Blogger i Embed this code:
>
> src="URL is an HTML Video" which is not playing in my Android Device
>   version is 4.4.1 & in my mom's Mobile the video is playing Andriod
>   Version is 6.0.

Comment: are you play video into web view or use any third party lib ?

Comment: I Have Blogger in-build API on my Application Android.......

Comment: please share you code into Question so i can get proper issues.